# Using Python, how do I tell if a rectangle and a shape overlap?

Tags: python, geometry

I'm writing a program in Python.  I have a series of shapes (polygons, defined as a sequence of coordinate pairs) and I need to tell if they overlap a particular rectangle.

Is there an easy algorithm for handling this?  Or, better, is there a pure Python library that can handle these calculations for me?

Comment: Are your aribitrary shapes really aribitrary shapes, or rather polygons?  Is the "sequence of coordinate pairs" describing the vertices of these polygons?  If not, what is it?

Comment: Clarified in the problem

Answer (score 3):

Presuming your "arbitrary shapes" are indeed polygons (given that they're described as coordinate pairs), determining if they overlap (in any language) is a relatively trivial calculation.  You merely need to compute if any side of polygon A intersects any other side of polygon B.

If you need an example, there's a rather thorough walkthrough at [the Drexel Math Forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20180109131024/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/63171.html).

There are a number of Python modules which can assist you in this pursuit, such as [Sympy](https://web.archive.org/web/20120423174751/http://docs.sympy.org:80/dev/modules/geometry.html), [Numpy](https://web.archive.org/web/20121108212849/http://numpy.scipy.org:80/), [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/), etc., but all of them are rather heavy if this is the only geometric calculation you need to make.

Comment: The "sides intersect" doesn't work, in the case where polygon A completely contains polygon B.

Comment: @Chris Check that the intersection point is between the endpoints of both sides you're checking (`xA1 <= xInt <= xA2 and xB1 <= xInt <= xB2 and yA1 <= yInt <= yA2 and yB1 <= yInt <= yB2`)

Comment: @Chris: If you want to include containment, you can use the crossing lines interior to the polygon.  It adds computation time, but not complexity.